# max of two integers using ternary operator in C

Tags: c, max, ternary-operator

Is there a better way to return the max of two integers using the ternary operator in C?

This is what I have for now

```
int max(int a, int b)
{
 int big = 0;
 big = (a>b)?a:b;

 return big;
}
```

But I wanted to write it something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 printf("%d\n",fun(5,4));

 return 0;
}

int fun(int a, int b)
{
 (a>b)?(return a:return b);
}
```

But it gives me an error

Comment: "It gives me an error" - because its not valid C. What's wrong with `return a > b ? a : b;`

Comment: You can't put parentheses around the second and third part of a ternary.

Comment: @WhozCraig, just came back after I found the solution, and see that it's answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The conditional operator (yes, it has a name!) is used to build *expressions*, so you have to use it where an expression is expected – for example, the expression of the return statement:

```
return b < a ? a : b;
```

Answer (score 3):

One improvement you can do is make the function `inline`

```
inline int max(int a, int b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

See Also [An Inline Function is As Fast As a Macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html).

Answer (score 2):

`return` is a statement, not an expression. It can't be used in the middle of an expression.

Also, the two return values of the ternary have to be separate expressions; wrapping them in a single set of parentheses makes them just one expression.

So it should be:

```
int fun(int a, int b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
```